# Segmentation fault on accessing raspberry pi's gpio address

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I have been following this tutorial
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok01.html
and as I want to control the gpio without replacing the OS, I want to just compile the assembly code, then run it like a program,

And I have changed the start of the program,

```
.global main
.func main

ldr r0,=0x20200000

mov r1,#1
lsl r1,#18


str r1,[r0,#4]

mov r1,#1
lsl r1,#16


str r1,[r0,#40]


loop: 
b loop
```

then do these on the Pi

```
as -o gpio.o main.s
gcc -o gpio gpio.o
```

but when I do

```
./gpio
```

I got segmentation fault

and when I do

```
sudo ./gpio
```

There is no segmentation fault but it does nothing, it suppose light the led then loop for ever, please help
I will appreciate anything related on how to access gpio using ARM assembly without replacing kernel.img.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you are following is for standalone ("bare metal") software running directly on the hardware, and you are attempting to run it under Linux. The kernel memory management correctly prevents you from attempting to access something that is not mapped into the process memory space.

If you check the return value of your sudo command, you will find that it still returns 139 (segmentation fault).

One way to achieve what you are attempting is by writing a kernel driver.
But a more practical one might be to make use of one of the software libraries already available for Linux on the raspberry pi. For example something like (random search, haven't used it) [WiringPi](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/).